# How do I find out which version of facebook api my AEM instance is using?

Tags: aem

Can somebody please tell me how do I find out which version of facebook API my AEM instance 6.1 is using. I basically want to determine if I am using v2.2 or v2.4 or v2.5. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook API depends on the version of your AEM and the feature packs installed on it. More details can be found at: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/communities/social-login.html#Facebook API Version

> Social login and the Geometrixx Facebook sample were developed when the Facebook Graph API was version 1.0.
>
> As of AEM 6.1 Communities FP4, social login was updated to work with the newer Facebook Graph API 2.5 version.
>
> As of AEM 6.1 Communities FP5, social login is more supportive of newer versions by default, with further customizations possible.

Comment: Hi. I agree with this. Suddenly facebook login has stopped working. We have not installed any FP till date. So want to determine which version of the graph api We are connecting to .

Comment: From your browser's network console look for calls like graph.facebook.com
  /vX.Y/{request-path} where X.Y is Fb older API version. If /vX.Y/ is not part of the path then you are using latest version. If it has completely stopped working then it could be something else so if you post the errors you are getting, it could be investigated.